# Using setNextMediaPlayer() for gapless video

Tags: android, video

I am trying to reduce the gap/pause when looping the same video with a seamless transition. Both setLooping and re-starting the video in onCompletion cause a noticeable pause. I noticed there is a setNextMediaPlayer() method which was created for gapless transition to a next MediaPlayer. It has been used successfully for audio. However with video, the surface can only be set to one mediaPlayer at a time. The only way I've managed to get it to work is by setting the surface to null of the first mediaPlayer and setting the surface to the actual surface for the second mediaPlayer in the first mediaPlayer's onCompletion. However, this introduces its own pause/gap and is no better than using one mediaPlayer to begin with.

Some code:

```
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Utils.logDebug(TAG, "mediaPlayer.onPrepared");

                if (mediaPlayer != null) { // && visible) { // check 
                    if (surface != null && powerManager.isScreenOn()) {
                        mediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);
                    }
                }
                mediaPlayer2.setNextMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);
                currentMediaPlayer = mediaPlayer;
                seekPlayerToCurrentPosition();
                startPlayer();
            }
        });

        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Utils.logDebug(TAG, "mediaPlayer.onCompletion");
                currentMediaPlayer.setSurface(null);
                currentMediaPlayer = mediaPlayer2;
                currentMediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);
            }
        });

        // MEDIA PLAYER 2

        mediaPlayer2.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Utils.logDebug(TAG, "mediaPlayer2.onPrepared");

                mediaPlayer.setNextMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer2);

            }
        });

        mediaPlayer2.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Utils.logDebug(TAG, "mediaPlayer2.onCompletion");
                currentMediaPlayer.setSurface(null);
                currentMediaPlayer = mediaPlayer;
                currentMediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);
            }
        });
```